# How does Entity Framework handle Complex types?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, xamarin

I am creating a `Xamarin.Forms` application that will be able to target multiple devices. In order to store data/preferences/etc I have to use `SQLite.Net`. As per documentation, and other users running into the issue, you can't use `complex types` as follows.

```
public class UserPreferences
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; } /// great
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string email { get; set; } /// strings are okay
        public byte[] byteArray {get; set;} ///storing blobs is fine
        ///... not okay below, because SQLite can't store complex types. I'm
        ///pretty sure even a List<string> isn't possible
        public List<Orders> favorites {get; set;}
}
```

This app will need to talk to a server as well. I understand the limitations on the client side, which means I will use `Serialization/Deserialization` and essentially `blob` storage with `SQLite`.

However, I got to thinking about the different options, either keep using `SQLite.net`, or use Entity on the serverside. I couldn't find any background information, on how Entity handles Complex Types, this is all I could find about how to use them. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680147.aspx

If I already have the logic for Serialization of the `byte[]` on the client-side, it would make my job easier.

Essentially, what I'm asking is, how does Entity handle storing/accessing the `Complex Types`? I will use this answer to deduce if I want my application(which will require thousands of transactions a second) to use `sqlite.net` or use `Entity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, SQLite doesn't store complex types on an entity, but neither does EF. It is two separate entities. So, just make another entity `Orders`. SQLite also doesn't handle relationships or navigation properties. If you do want the foreignkey relationships handled automatically, check out https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions. It works pretty well as long as you configure the relationship correctly.

Comment: Great answer Here. The real kicker is sqlite is basically a storage method for files. It is not a true database.